# Hibernate Envers modifiedFlag column name

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers 5.3.7 and have the following Entity:

```
@Audited(withModifiedFlag=true)
public class MyEntity {

    @Column(name = "item_condition")
    private String condition;
```

As you can see the column name in the database differs from the property name.
If I try to save the entity then envers throws an exception:

```
Cause: Unknown column 'condition_mod' in 'field list'
Query is: insert into MyEntity (revtype, item_condition, condition_mod,
```

Is there any way to control the modified flag column name? Something like to use the main column name defined in my entity or just define the modifiedFlag column name for a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the issue [HHH-10398](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10398?filter=18161).

In Hibernate Envers 5.x and prior, the modified flags support has always build the mod-columns based on the actual property name rather than the `@Column` annotation as its basis.  This is why you're noticing that the insert fails, it expects your schema to have a column named `condition_mod`.

As a workaround, you can explicitly specify the modified column's full name using the `@Audited` annotation on the property until the above referenced issue is resolved and a strategy pattern implemented to support future and backward compatibility.

In your case, you'd annotate the property as follows:

```
@Column(name = "item_condition")
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, modifiedColumnName = "item_condition_mod")
private String condition;
```

In Hibernate 6, I plan to introduce a `ModifiedColumnNameNamingStrategy` where there will be a legacy impl to support backward compatibility and an enhanced impl  that will be able to allow you to simply specify the `@Column` annotation and Envers will instead use that as a basis for the column name rather than the property.

But until that gets added, the workaround is the only alternative for 5.x and before.

---

**UPDATE**: A fix for [HHH-10398](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10398?filter=18161) has been scheduled for inclusion in version 5.4.6.Final.

Comment: Was there any update for the modifiedFlag column name to be based on @JoinColumn? Or did some workaround appear so that I don't have to specify the modifiedColumnName in each @JoinColumn?

Answer (score 3):

As explained by @Naros, this can be done now with adding the following setting:

```
org.hibernate.envers.modified_column_naming_strategy: improved
```

Or, for Spring applications:

```
spring.jpa.org.hibernate.envers.modified_column_naming_strategy: improved
```

Notice the default value is `legacy`, which simply adds `MODIFIED_FLAG_SUFFIX` to the end of class field name (rather than column name).